# Trying to remove old PHP version

Tags: php, ubuntu

I am trying to install PHP 5.3.8 on my Kubuntu box.  I made the mistake of trying to build 5.3.8 from source while 5.3.5 was still installed (APT package).  So I did ./configure which succeeded, then tried to apt-get remove php5, then tried rebuilding again, and now my phpinfo() ALWAYS shows 5.3.5 even though I have tried to manually remove every trace of PHP and rebuild 5.3.8.  I've tried removing all PHP files and directories from /usr/lib, /usr/share, /var/lib, etc etc.  Also tried remove --purge on libapache2-mod-php5 and reinstall.  I don't know where it's seeing PHP.  Even the paths showing up on phpinfo() have been removed and it STILL gives me the 5.3.5 info page.  Any ideas on what I should try next???  I don't want to rebuild my system again!

Answer (score 0):

You say you've done configure, but have you run make & make install?

If an old version of PHP is residing in your system, your phpinfo should provide valuable clues to where it's being stored.

Edit:
From the comments below, I'd say you need to add 'apache2' to your PHP configure. This generates a module for PHP to be used with Apache.

Comment: Yes I've run make, make test, make install.  Interestingly, the CLI was installed and phpversion() returns 5.3.8.  But phpinfo() is still 5.3.5 and it still shows up even if I delete PHP files from EVERY path showing on phpinfo.  Very weird.  And yes I have cleared my browser cache :)

Comment: AFAIK if it's being run with Apache then you'll have the Apache module loaded somewhere. Ie libphp5.so which for a Gentoo system exists:
/usr/lib/php5.3/apache2/libphp5.so
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so

Comment: BTW what are your configure parameters for PHP?

Comment: I removed and reinstalled the PHP module, and it is enabled.  Configure parameter is just --with-mysql

Comment: Force the Apache config to read from wherever the source is installing the module to?